# Why does it follow from $ns = 1 - ar$ that $ar \equiv 1 \mod n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, equivalence-relations

I'm reading through Prof. Tom Judson's online textbook "Abstract Algebra: Theory and Applications".  Proposition 3.4 (under the heading [The Integers mod n](http://abstract.ups.edu/aata/section-mod-n-sym.html#groups-subsection-integers-mod-n)) states:

"Let $\Bbb Z_n$ be the set of equivalence classes of the integers $\mod n$ and $a,b,c∈\Bbb Z_n$."

and, under (6):

"Let $a$ be a nonzero integer. Then $\gcd(a,n)=1$ if and only if there exists a multiplicative inverse $b$ for $a \mod n$; that is, a nonzero integer $b$ such that $ab \equiv 1 \mod n$."

The first part of the proof for this states:

"Suppose that $\gcd(a,n)=1$. Then there exist integers $r$ and $s$ such that $ar+ns=1$. Since $ns=1−ar$, it must be the case that $ar≡1 \mod n$. Letting $b$ be the equivalence class of $r$, $ab \equiv 1 \mod n$."

I'm following everything just fine except for this one sentence from the preceding paragraph:

"Since $ns=1-ar$, it must be the case that $ar \equiv 1 \mod n$."

As in the title to this question, why does it follow from $ns = 1 - ar$ that $ar \equiv 1 \mod n$?  It's obvious to me that $ns = 1 - ar$, but not that this implies $ar \equiv 1 \mod n$.  The entire rest of the proof (including the second part not copied here) makes perfect sense to me.  Just that one sentence eludes me.

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Thank you.  Working on it.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown how's that?

Comment: For a lot of people, that is the *definition* of what it means for two things to be equal in modular arithmetic. What definition are you using, then?

Comment: @rschwieb IIRC, the definition presented in the book was that if $a \equiv b \mod n$ then $a-b=kn$ for some integer $k$.  I see now that these are equivalent.  I think the order in which the author wrote the terms may have confused me.  I haven't been in a math lecture in about a decade and a half.  I recently brushed up on some topics I hadn't touched in years (like linear algebra) and decided it might be fun to go further than I did in school.  Challenging so far.

Comment: Oh jeez, that's exactly the same form, isn't it?  Feeling sheepish now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We say that $a \equiv b \text{ mod } n$ if we can write $a = b + kn$ for some integer $k$.

In your example, we have $1 = ar + ns$.

Comment: So, $ar = 1 - ns$ and therefore $ar$ is equal to $1$ plus some (in this case, negative) multiple of $n$?  Am I following you?

Comment: In other words, this could be written as $ar = 1 + (-s)n$.

Comment: @burfl Yes, that's also correct. I see that in your source $a \equiv m \text{ mod } n$ is defined as $n|(a-b)$. This is in fact equivalent to the definition I gave.

Comment: Yes, I see that now.  I'm feeling rather silly that this eluded me.  But your nudge is greatly appreciated!  Thank you.